# How should be dependency between projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies, project-management, projects-and-solutions

How much the projects should be independent of each other?

I have a very big Visual Studio solution, in which all the projects are dependent to each other. I am not able to take a single project from the solution and add it to another solution in another computer,  because they are all tied to each other.

Am I doing the things correctly?

---

For example;

Consider these three of my projects (Disk File, Data Converter and Math - .h and .cpp file pairs are C++ classes; I will mention these by their respective name):

```
The Solution
|
|---- Disk File
|     |
|     |---- BinaryFile.h, BinaryFile.cpp
|     |---- TextFile.h, TextFile.cpp
|
|---- Data Converter
|     |
|     |---- Utf8.h, Utf8.cpp
|     |---- XmlParser.h, XmlParser.cpp
|     |---- StringFormatter.h, StringFormatter.cpp
|
|---- Math
      |
      |---- Plotter2D.h, Plotter2D.cpp
      |---- Matrix.h, Matrix.cpp
```

- `TextFile` uses `Utf8` for character encoding. That makes `Disk File` dependent to `Data Converter`.
- `XmlParser` uses `TextFile`. That makes `Data Converter` dependent to `Disk File`.
- `Plotter2D` uses `TextFile` for dumping some data to use it with and external software, and `Matrix` uses some string formatter tools in its `::ToString()` method. That makes `Math` dependent to both `Disk File` and `Data Converter`.

This is just an example of dependencies between several classes. In fact, I have much more files in my solution. It is a total mess of code dependencies.

I will start a project with one of my friends. He needs my `Math` project in his solution. But it won't be easy for him to adapt it to his own solution, because it will give a lot of compiler errors regarding these dependencies.

Is this amount of dependencies normal? Am I doing it correctly? How about I keep a copy of all common files in every project they are needed it (this may be silly, I'm just asking it)?

I need your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be such dependencies but you can avoid them using some of the methods:

1. to keep the .h files independent by not including cross module headers, instead use forward declaration there and use the actual header files in the .cpp files.
2. For enums defined in other headers to be passed in a function, one can use void pointers to pass and validate the value in .cpp files.
3. Also you can used "extern C" functions.

Answer (score 0):

Managing dependencies is usually a complex problem. The main point that you already seem to be following is that dependencies should create an acyclic graph.

Beyond that, you should try to break the dependencies as much as possible. For example, does `XmlParser` really need `TextFile`? Or could an application that wants to parse a text file intantiate the latter, read the contents into a string and pass it to `XmlParser`? If you manage to to the second, then `XmlParser` no longer depends on `TextFile`.

Another thing to consider is the *type* of dependency that you are creating. Using the same example, is `TextFile` used in the public interface of `XmlParser`? Does it need to be used there? If `XmlParser` depends on `TextFile` you will need to link the library, if it is part of the interface, then users of `XmlParser` will have to include the headers of `TextFile` creating higher coupling. In this case, you could for example pass a file name to `XmlParser` instead of a `TextFile` to remove the dependency from the interface.

At the end of the day, this is a bit of an art. Focus on having the least possible number of dependencies and for those that are required, try to make the coupling minimal.

Another thing is the math library. I would break the dependency to `TextFile`. The extra functionality can be provided in a separate library that handles serialization of the math components. This would allow users of `Math` that don't require file backup not to depend on the `TextFile` component.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach was to avoid dependency cycle between projects, in your case utility classes like for "Disk File" and "Data Converter" could be existing in the same project, and you can use namespaces to enforce modularity.

And to have a good idea of your dependencies it's recommended to use tools like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) or [CppDepend](http://www.CppDepend.com) to detect all dependencies between your projects and maybe gain time when searching all dependencies needed for the specific functionality you want to give to your friend.